# Can you break up a pairwise comparison into components, so that individual participants don't have to assess every possible comparison?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, experiment-design

I'm trying to do a pairwise comparison for 40 items. However, this results in $\frac{40 \times 39}{2} = 780$ combinations. Obviously no-one is going to sit through a survey that long. Is there a way of breaking down a pairwise comparison so that participants each only assess a subset of these possible comparisons?

For example, if I had 3 things being rated, this would give the following comparisons:

- 1 with 2
- 1 with 3
- 2 with 3

Could this be broken down between three participants $P_i$ so that....

- $P_1$ assesses 1,2 and 1,3
- $P_2$ assesses 2,3 and 1,2
- $P_3$ assesses 1,3 and 2,3

or is this a statistical no-no?

Comment: I have attempted to clarify some of the wording and formatting. Feel free to revert any changes you don't agree with.

Comment: Are the pairwise comparisons just a correlation between, e.g., all of the ratings given to item 1 and all of those given to item 2? Is it a single rating that each person gives each item, or do they rate them on more than one scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've outlined can be described as a "full factorial" experimental design where participants are exposed to all of the possible combinations of the choice set. Obviously, this is an impossibly time-consuming research task, even for a relatively small set of options. I'm not an expert in this methodology, but "fractional factorial" designs offer one way out of the mess. This Wiki article describes their logic ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_factorial_design